# Understanding the output of xrandr --query

Tags: xorg, xrandr

I called the `xrandr --query` command in the shell to find out display-connectors and displays connected.

It is displayed:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768      60.02 +
   1280x720      59.97  
   1152x768      59.95  
   1024x768      59.95  
   800x600       59.96  
   848x480       59.94  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I roughly understand what all this means:

There are LVDS, HDMI-0 and VGA-0 connectors.
There is nothing connected to the VGA-0 connector.
There is a display connected to the LVDS connector. The modes in which that display can be used are listed. But it is not in use.
There is a display connected to the HDMI-0 connector. The modes in which that display can be used are listed.  `*+` in the list of modes denotes that that display is in use as primary display in the mode `1920x1080 60.00 50.00 59.94`.

But I do not understand everything.

In particular:

**Question 1:**

I do not understand what the very first line
`Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192`
is about.

What is it about?

(None of the displays connected does provide a mode `320 x 200`.
None of the displays connected does provide a mode  `8192 x 8192`.)

**Question 2:**

I do not understand what the string `(normal left inverted right x axis y axis)` in the line for the display at HDMI-0 means.

Can someone tell me what this means?

The reason for the question is:

I wish to have a command line where `xrandr` is called so that all displays except for this HDMI-0 display are turned off.

So far I have the following command line:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --off --output LVDS --off --output HDMI-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
```

Does the said string `(normal left inverted right x axis y axis)` indicate that `xrandr`  needs to be called with a set of parameters differing from the set of parameters provided in the command line I've got so far?

If so: Which set of parameters?

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple displays, you can put them next to each other and/or under each other and imagine that this way you get a large total area on which things are displayed.

From the other direction, you can imagine that there is a large total area that is divided into the partial areas that are formed by your individual displays that are placed next to and under each other.

The line with `Screen 0` refers to this large total area and indicates the minimum and maximum dimensions that this large total area can have. These dimensions depend on the hardware of the computer, e.g. the available memory of the graphics card(s).

"normal left inverted right" refer to whether the display you are looking at from the front is standing there not rotated, or rotated 90 degrees to the left, or rotated 180 degrees (upside down), or rotated 90 degrees to the right.

For the large total area, you can think of a Cartesian coordinate system that has an x-axis going to the right and a y-axis going down, and whose axis origin is in the upper left corner of this large total area.

x axis and y axis indicate the coordinates where the upper left corner of a single display should be placed in the large total area.

For example, if you have two displays side by side and the left display is 1366 units wide, like your LVDS-device, then the upper left corner of this display in the large total area has the coordinates x-axis 0 and y-axis 0.
If you don't want the left and the right display to show partially the same things, then the upper left corner of the right display must be shifted 1366 units to the right on the large total area and have the coordinates x-axis 1366 and y-axis 0.

If you have installed e.g. the ARandR screen layout editor, you can save the xrandr command line for all your currently used screens by clicking on the menu "Layout" -> "Save as" as a .sh file, i.e. as a text file which should contain a shell script.

Viewing this text file in a text editor can be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

#### Terminology

Words like *monitor*, *screen*, *display* and so on are near-synonyms, but in a given technical context, they can have different meanings. Unfortunately, the same word can have a different meaning in different communities. In this answer, I'll use the word *monitor* to mean a physical object that displays images on a (generally) rectangular canvas, typically a computer monitor (or something similar such as a video projector).

As far as the X window system is concerned, a *display* is a logical entity to which applications can connect and on which they can display windows, receive input, and do a few other things. A display can have multiple monitors, or can be connected to a virtual “monitor” that is not a physical device, for example a network connection for remote displays.

A *screen* is an obsolete concept. It's the original way X managed multiple monitors: a display could have multiple screens, each representing one monitor. An application had to choose which screen to display a window on; a window could not span multiple screens and could not move between screens. Due to these limitations, the concept has been mostly abandoned, but the operating system still supports it and the terminology still comes up here and there. Nowadays, there's just one *screen* that can span multiple monitors.

An *output* is the term that Xrandr uses to mean a port on the computer onto which a monitor. A “connected” output is a port on which a monitor is present (or a port on which the presence of a monitor cannot be reliably determined).

#### Question 1: screen dimensions

The display (technically the screen, but as we saw above in the modern world a display has a single screen) is a rectangular canvas on which windows can be displayed. The dimensions of this canvas typically change when the monitor configuration changes: it's adjusted to be the smallest rectangle that all the monitors fit in.

The first line indicates the minimum possible, current and maximum possible dimensions of this canvas. Each monitor shows a rectangular part of the canvas, aligned with the axes.

The minimum and maximum dimensions are only relevant when the monitor configuration changes. Parts of the canvas that are not shown by any monitor are effectively invisible. For example, if you had a single, tiny 320x160 monitor, the canvas would have to be at least 320x160 and the bottom half of the canvas would be invisible.

On the line for each monitor, the numbers after `(dis)connected` indicate the dimensions and the position of the monitor. For example, if you had a second monitor of the same size to the right of HDMI-0, that monitor would show `1920x1080+1920+0`. If that second monitor was below HDMI-0, it would show `1920x1080+0+1080`.

#### Question 2: monitor transformations

A monitor normally shows the pixel (x=0,y=0) (relative to the monitor's origin) at the top left, the pixel (x=1,y=1) immediately to its right, etc. If your system supports it (and most modern ones do), the monitor can be instructed to show the output differently. This can be configured with `xrandr --rotate … --reflect …`. The words in parentheses indicate the possible transformations.

For example, `left` rotates the picture 90° clockwise, and `right` rotates the picture 90° anticlockwise. This is useful if you've rotated the monitor correspondingly, typically because your monitor is wider than it's tall (landscape) but you want a displayed area that's taller than it's wide (portrait) so you rotate it. For example, after `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --rotate left`, the corresponding line will change to

```
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
```

`inverted` shows the image rotated upside-down. `x axis` (the two words are a single thing) shows the image flipped upside-down. `y axis` shows the image flipped around a vertical axis (in case for some reason you want to look at your monitor in a mirror). You can combine a rotation and a reflection. You can even specify `--rotate inverted --reflect xy` which shows the image normally since the composition of two orthogonal flips and a 180° turn is the identity transformation.

#### Enabling a single output

> I wish to have a command line where xrandr is called so that all displays except for this HDMI-0 display are turned off.

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --off --output LVDS --off --output HDMI-0 --auto
```

- `--auto` is the strange way xrandr spells “on” (i.e. “active”). It's the opposite of `--off`.
- `--primary` is not useful when there's a single active monitor.
- `--pos` lets you specify the position of the monitor on the canvas. 0x0 is the default so you don't need to specify it. It's somewhat unusual to use `--pos` explicitly; most often you'd use one of `--mirror`, `--right-of`, `--left-of`, `--above` or `--below` to position monitors relative to each other.
- `--mode` is not useful unless you want to pick a mode that's different from the default, or to switch back from a non-default mode. The default is usually the best choice.
- `--rotate` is not useful unless you want to pick a non-default rotation, or to switch back from a non-default rotation. The default rotation is usually the right one unless you've rotated your monitor to be in a portrait format, in which case you need `--rotate left` or `--rotate right`.

Comment: I really like the way you define the terms at the beginning of the answer when they can become confusing if not used carefully.

Comment: But according to https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml#heading14 which says "A “screen” represents the binding of a graphics device (Device section) and a monitor (Monitor section)" and given that a "Screen" section can have multiple Display subsections, I'm perceiving "monitors" and "screens" a "1:1" ratio, while "screen" and "displays" a "1:N" ratio. Therefore, a "monitor" can have multiple "displays". So I'm a bit confused when you said "A display can have multiple monitors".

Comment: @yaobin This is a different meaning of the word “display”! I didn't discuss it because it isn't used much (though maybe a little more than screens?). The `Display` subsections of a `Screen` are basically different predefined configurations of the association between the screen and the monitor. A monitor can have multiple predefined configurations, though only one will be active at a given time.